# Deepin Music Player Media Keys

Tags: 16.04, music, music-player, media-buttons

it's probably up to deepin to support it but is there a way to get media keys for Deepin in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: What's your Linux distribution? Did you install Deepin media player in Ubuntu or use the one that was shipped with Deepin Linux? It [supposedly](https://www.fossmint.com/deepin-music-player-for-ubuntu-linux-mint/) supports global hotkeys which should include media keys in theory although the author claims that it didn't for him.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 64bit and I installed it using the software center. which is a gui but in the background I suspect it just runs sudo apt install...